# Wordpress: как получить адрес ссылки get_next_post_link()

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Функции `get_previous_post_link()` и `get_next_post_link()` выводят на страницу тег `a` со всеми атрибутами. Мне нужно получить только содержимое `href`, то есть собственно адрес ссылки. В документации и поиске ничего по этому поводу не нашёл (может быть, плохо искал).

Решил задачу через `preg_match`:

```
$prev = get_previous_post_link();
$next = get_next_post_link();
if (preg_match('/href=\"(.*?)\"/', $prev, $match) == 1) {
    $prev_link = $match[1];
}
else if(preg_match('/href=\"(.*?)\"/', $next, $match) == 1) {
    $next_link = $match[1];
}
```

Но по мне так это не айс. Есть ли более изящные решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте таким образом

```
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();
$link = get_permalink( $next_post ); // Ваша ссылка
```

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо!